# Referencing types in monorepo in sibling directory (going below root)

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Would someone know how to help to solve a problem of referencing types in a TypeScript monorepo project? Or if it is even possible in the following setting.

The structure is like

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── lib/
│   └── workers/
│       ├── types.ts
│       ├── hello.ts
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── frontend/
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── openwcMiniflare.ts
```

where `frontend/tsconfig.json` references types like `import { WorkerMethods, WorkerEvents } from 'workers/types';` with configuration such as (relevant parts, full source [here](https://github.com/veikkoeeva/openwc-miniflare/blob/main/frontend/tsconfig.json))

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "paths": {
      "workers/*": ["../lib/workers/*"]
    },
  }
  "references": [
    { "path": "../lib/workers" }
  ]
}
```

`workers/types.ts`

```
export type WorkerMethods = {
  sum: (x: number, y: number) => number;
  mul: (x: number, y: number) => number;
};

export type WorkerEvents = {
  ping: string;
};
```

I don't understand how VS Code gives the following error message and indeed, it looks like the types are undefined during runtime.

[image]

**BUT!** If I change the definition like `import { WorkerMethods, WorkerEvents } from '../../lib/workers/types';`, then error message tells they're outside of `rootDir`.

Is structure like this even possible with VS Code?

Comment: https://nx.dev/ can help a lot with a monorepo like this.

Comment: @AlexWayne Looks good! But I wonder if this one can be pulled without. Incidentally I was eyeing towards that and [https://rushjs.io/](RushJs] but didn't think either one would help to get the build to work and it's something else going on here. I don't have much experience TS, but I think they can't also put under same `package.json` in this case, as Chai complains about missing `dom` that the Web Worker lib can't include. And it's a better arrangement in any case. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! This is embarrassing, also a bit strange. This configuration does in fact work after I cleaned up `node_modules` and lock files. I have no idea what could have been the problem and if the cause was about this or doing this cleaning just contributed in such a way the solution works.

In any event, if/when someone looks into this issue, that configuration should work (remembering the usual `tsc --build` on composite projects and `tsc --project <directory>\tsconfig.json` or a combination thereof).